# Parsing a complex JSON file

Tags: java, json, parsing, gwt

I need to parse a JSON file and put the data into a HTML table. I am using GWT for this application, the data shall be read from the file on the server side and passed to the client on page load.

The format for the JSONObjects in the file are as follows:

```
{  
"Object 1": [
{ "value1": [ "subKey1", "subValue2" ], "value2": "val", "value3": { "key1": val1, "key2": val2, "key3": val3} },
{ "value2": [ "subKey1", "subValue2" ], "value2": "val", "value3": { "key1": val1, "key2": val2, "key3": val3} },
....
....
],

"Object 2": [
{ "value1": [ "subKey1", "subValue2" ], "value2": "val", "value3": { "key1": val1, "key2": val2, "key3": val3} },
{ "value2": [ "subKey1", "subValue2" ], "value2": "val", "value3": { "key1": val1, "key2": val2, "key3": val3} },
....
....
],
 ....

}
```

Up until now, I have only done simple JSON parsing. The problem I am having here is that the data I am working with has a unique name for each object so I cannot seem to parse them into an array of JSONObjects.

I have attempted to parse them (using JSON simple) this way but I am throwing an error.

```
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obj;
            obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("file.json"));

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        array.add(obj.get("Object1"));
        array.add(obj.get("Object2"));
        array.add(obj.get("Object3"));
        array.add(obj.get("Object4"));

        JSONObject jo;

        for (Object o : array) {
            jo = (JSONObject) o;
        }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But this throws an error:

```
    org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

Another method from my understanding is to create a POJO class for the objects but since each JSONObject has a different identifier, does that mean each object must have its own unique class? Some JSON2Java methods I have used just create a new class for each of them.

Comment: Why not just pass the JSON directly to the GWT application? Why parse it server side?

Comment: Thats another option too, I was just wondering how I would structure the data into a table. i figured making a POJO for the data would make it easier.

Comment: JSON _is_ JavaScript! It's 1,000 times easier to deal with it _in_ JavaScript than in Java. Okay, maybe that's a slight exaggeration. But parse it **for free** on the client side because it's _already a JavaScript object_ - clue's in the name... I would start by [reading the tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html) - overlay types are truly magical.

Comment: OK, I just parsed the entire .json file as a string to the client. Then parses it  using safeEval(). My next question is that since I am parsing entire file as one string, can safeEval() return it as an array of JSONOBjects I can then assign to an array of Overlays?

Comment: You JSON doesn't seem to have a valid root object, `{}`; if it does not, then it is not valid JSON. If it is indeed wrapped in a root object, then the object representation should be a `Map<String, Overlay>`.

Comment: I am kinda new to complex JSON parsing but wouldn't the names "object1" and "object2" count as root objects for each respective JSON Object listed in the JSON file?

Comment: JSON **must** have a **single** root object, either an object  - `{}` - or an array - `[]`; much like XML. If this is actually your JSON, then it is not _valid JSON_. You could, for example, try and split it into multiple valid JSON objects; but that is rather painful. I would suggest you fix the generation side to create valid JSON in the first place.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I misunderstood what a root element is. My file does have surrounding brackets in the JSON file. I have edited the example JSON in the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the instance of the Object before casting it:

```
for (Object obj : array) {
    if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
       // It's an array
       yourJsonArray = (JSONArray)obj;
    } else if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
       // It's an object
       yourJsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
    } else {
       // It's string, number...
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think this is somewhat of an XY problem - as the OP is trying parse parse JSON server side to send it to a GWT frontend over RPC; i.e. deserialise it, serialise it, and deserialise it once again. Although this is certainly one way to fix the exact issue the OP is having, I don't believe it's the correct answer to the underlying question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You're right! maybe it doesn't solve the main problem but it should fix the Exception of his attempt.